# MongoDB Aggregate $min not calculating

Tags: mongodb-query

I am using the aggregate:

```
db.quantum_auto_keys.aggregate([
{$match: {table_name: 'PIZZA_ORDERS'}},
    {
        $group: { 
                    _id: { onDate: { $dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: '$created_on', timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles'}}, table_name: '$table_name' },          
                    min: { $min: '$last_number' }
    }},
    {$sort: {_id: 1}}
]);
```

It ignores the onDate grouping and returns the min for the collection where table_name = PIZZA_ORDERS.

When I use $max it calculates the maximum pizza orders by day.  $count also returns the number of orders per day correctly.

How should I go about getting the minimum and maximum values via Aggregate or is there a different way to get that information from my collection?

Comment: I am running MongoDB server version: 3.6.8 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I updated to MongoDB 4.4 and the table_name was not the correct group.  Changing it to include another field got min calculation to be correct.